# Can Godot and GDScript store functions in variables?

Tags: function, scripting, godot, gdscript

I am confused by part of the Godot Docs for the [GDScript language](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html). About midway down the page, in the "Referencing Functions" section, it says you can't store functions in variables, and then seems to immediately contradict itself.

*Can Godot functions be stored in variables or not?*

> **Referencing Functions**
>
> Contrary to Python, functions are not first class objects in GDScript. 
>   This means ***they cannot be stored in variables***, passed as an argument to another function or be returned from other functions. This is for performance reasons.
>
> To reference a function by name at runtime, (e.g. ***to store it in a variable,*** or pass it to another function as an argument) one must use the call or funcref helpers:

Answer (score 24, accepted):

GDScript functions are not objects like they are in python. So, you cannot directly reference a function.

However, you can indirectly reference them by name using their associated instance.

For example with the following function:

```
func hello():
    print('Hello')
```

You can call a function on an instance by name:

```
call('hello') # prints 'Hello'
```

You can store an instance and function name with `funcref()`:

```
var ref = funcref(hello_object_instance, 'hello')
ref.call_func() # prints 'Hello'
takes_func_ref_to_call_later(ref) # later, prints 'Hello'
```

`FuncRef.call_func()` does the same thing as `Object.call()` it just wraps it in an object.

Consequently, a common pattern for callback functions, as shown by `Object.connect()` and friends, is:

```
func deferred_finish(param1, param2, callback_obj, callback_func):
    # ... do something
    callback_ref = funcref(callback_obj, callback_func)
func _process(delta):
    if _finished:
        callback_ref.call_func()
func _enter_tree():
    deferred_finish('hello', 'world', self, 'finished_callback')
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if you would like any clarifications.

Comment: Just to add: There are plans to add function-variables and lambda syntax in Godot 3.2, see https://github.com/godotengine/godot-roadmap/issues/23. Given the existing release history, that may well happen in 2020.

Comment: Update mentioned in @adabru 's comment seems postponed to version 4.0.

Answer (score 4):

It's not available in 3.x as far as I know, but it is a feature in Godot 4.0, see the docs on [referencing functions](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#referencing-functions) (and the following section on lambdas

Basically you can declare a variable using

```
var f = func foo(x):
    <function body>
```

and then `f.call(x)` to call the function stored in that variable.